# Swift - Sorting objects received from db in tableviewSections by date

Tags: swift, uitableview, grouping

I have an app that receives transactions from a database and displays them in a tableview in date order. Now I want to place transactions from each day in a separate section like this:

```
Today: 
transaction455
transaction454

Yesterday:
transaction453

Tuesday, 12.11:
transaction452
transaction451
transaction450
```

the transaction-object has a "createDate" which is in Unix so I have to convert it to date first. Then I sort all the dates in `var sectionHeaders = [String]()`

My main issue is the `numberOfRowsInSection`, I have watched and read multiple tutorials on how to implement this but I simply can't. This is my code so far:

Grouping transactions:

```
var sectionHeaders = [String]()

func groupTransactions() {
        print("Attemt to group transactions based on date")

        let sortedTransactionSections = transactions.sorted(by: {$0.createdDate > $1.createdDate})

        let groupedTransactions = Dictionary(grouping: sortedTransactionSections) { (element) -> String in
            return unixToString(t: Double(element.createdDate), f: "EEEE, dd MM")
        }

        groupedTransactions.keys.forEach { (key) in
            sectionHeaders.append(key)
        }

        let sorted = sectionHeaders.sorted(by: {$0 > $1})
        print(sorted)

    }
```

One big problem in this grouping is that is groups depending on the first letter of the day. 
So all "Friday" first, then "Monday", then "Saturday" and so on... while I want them grouped on the actual date: "14.11.2019", "13.11.2019", "12.11.2019" etc...

Tableview:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if isSearching {
            return 1
        } else {
            return sectionHeaders.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionHeaders[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isSearching {
            return filteredTransactions.count
        } else {

            return transactions.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! TransactionCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        var rec: Transactions
        transactions = transactions.sorted(by: {$0.createdDate > $1.createdDate})

        if isSearching {
            rec = filteredTransactions[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            rec = transactions[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.dateLabel.text = unixToString(t: Double(rec.createdDate), f: "H:mm MMM dd")
        cell.amountLabel.text = rec.transactionTotal.convertPrice

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: So, there is 2 problems, first, you need to find a way to group your dates, maybe by grouping them by "14.11.2019", "13.11.2019", ... and then renaming the group the way you want. Second : "numberOfSections" should return the number group (in your example 3) and "numberOfRowsInSection" should return the number of row for each section (so 2 for "today", 1 for "yesterday" and 3 for "Tuesday, 12.11" in a way likes sectionHeaders[section].count)

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. I got everything to work except the "numberOfRowsInSection", each section is returning "todays" transactions with sectionHeaders[section].count. Maybe something missing in cellForRowAt ?

Comment: Yes maybe, in "cellForRowAt" you should access to your data in a way like transactions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]